# Have you got /gotten it? Do you get it?

Tags: sentence-meaning

(A teacher explaining a math question) Bla bla bla,... that is why x=45.

> Have you got it? (BE)

> Have you gotten it? (AE)

> Do you get it?

Which is most idiomatic?

Comment: "Which a person prefers" depends on whether they are British or American!

Comment: Do British people prefer 1 and 3, while American people do 2 and 3?

Comment: 1 and 2 are identified as 'British English' and 'American English'. Other than that, opinion-based questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most resources will tell you that "gotten" is chiefly American/Canadian, used as the past participle of "get", whereas British English speakers (and almost every other dialect of English) use "got".

However, there are some idiomatic exceptions. For example, British English speakers do use the expression "ill-gotten gains".

It should also be noted that American English speakers use "got" interchangeably with "have", for example, "you got mail".

Regarding your specific example - [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20you%20get%20it%2C%20have%20you%20got%20it%2C%20have%20you%20gotten%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20you%20get%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20got%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20gotten%20it%3B%2Cc0) would seem to suggest that "do you get it?" is overwhelmingly the more popular expression in selected literature. If you adjust the filter for American / British English, it remains the highest, showing that even the different uses of 'got/gotten' are not skewing the results.

Comment: Thank you very much. The next day in class,  the teacher asks again whether the students have understood it. Which is better? Is the answer still "do you get it?"

Comment: @Stephen I've used a dictionary and google ngrams to answer your original question. How about you use the same to answer your supplementary question?

Comment: Thank you, but I can't do this research, because we can't visit google. It's blocked.